# how i code the SplashScreenActivity.kt cuz mine doesn't work please take a look

Tags: android, kotlin, splash-screen

i want to add a splash screen to my app so i created an activity with a name of SplashScreen and i add this code to the SplashScreenActivity.kt but the android studio doesnt reconize java in
`val i = Intent(this@MainActivity, MainActivity::class.java)` and it shown as red Note that i use kotlin

```
package com.example.textnav

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Handler
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity


class SplashScreen : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 3000L

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen)


                Handler().postDelayed(
                    {
                        val i = Intent(this@MainActivity, MainActivity::class.java)
                        
                        startActivity(i)
                        finish()
                    }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT
                )
            }
        }
```

look at that https://ibb.co/bmjVHNV
the mainactivity.kt

```html
package com.example.textnav

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}
```

Comment: val i = Intent(this@SplashScreen, MainActivity::class.java)

Comment: Also, share the manifest life code

Comment: how pls show me